# Entity Framework entity is null but count is greater than 0

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Very strange issue with EF6. I have a `DbSet<T>` property defined on the context. Let's just say `T` is `Entity`, so it looks like this:

```
public virtual DbSet<Entity> Entities { get; set; }
```

If I say `Entities.Count()`, I get back a non-zero result. In this case, 504. However, here's where it gets strange:

```
var entity = context.Entities.First()
```

`entity` is `null`! When I log the underlying query, it looks absolutely fine. If I execute this query directly on the underlying database (which happens to be PostgreSQL, not SQL Server), it returns the right data.

I should also add that there are a large number of other models (over 40 of them), and they work just fine. Only this one does not.

The model itself is just a POCO with the usual virtual properties defined, e.g.,

```
class Entity {
    public virtual string Property1 { get; set; }
}
```

And so on. Nothing special.

Why do I get a non-zero count (which is accurate), but the entities themselves are always `null`?

Comment: _Nothing special_? `Entity`, at least, has no `PK`

Comment: You're right, @SlavaUtesinov, there was no PK. Unfortunately I did not design that database, which was done by people with poor knowledge of proper database design. (There were many other problems beyond the lack of PKs: lack of good normalization, incorrect data types, no `CHECK` constraints, etc.)